# Only allowing owner of comment to delete their comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise for user authentication.  And have three models, Articles, Comments and Users.

I have the ability for only logged in users to add a comment to an article. And I also have the comment adding the user id in the comments table.  However, I am struggling to implement the feature of restricting only the comment author to delete their own comment.

What I have:

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  has_many :comments
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_comment, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :comment_auth, only:  [:edit, :update, :destroy]


      #Some items removed for brevity

def destroy
          @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id]).destroy
          redirect_to article_path(@article)
      end

  private

  def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body, :user_id)
  end

  def find_comment
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  end

  def comment_auth
      if @comment.user_id != current_user.id
        flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner of this comment.'
      redirect_to(root_path)
      end
  end
```

I also added a foreign key on the comments table:

```
class AddForeignKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :comments, :users
  end
end
```

Then when trying to delete a comment from a user I created and is logged in, I get:

```
NoMethodError in CommentsController#destroy
undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

This is before filter and `@comment` is not initialized yet. `@comment` you are assigning in `destroy` action is not available in `before_filter`

```
def comment_auth
  if @comment.user_id != current_user.id
    flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner of this comment.'
  redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

**Solution:** You can remove `comment_auth` and change `destroy` action to:

```
def destroy
  @comment = 
    current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id], article_id: @article)
  if @comment && @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article), notice: 'comment deleted successfully'
  else      
    redirect_to article_path(@article), alert: 'something went wrong'
  end
end
```

**OR** Change `comment_auth` to

```
def comment_auth
  @comment = 
    current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id], article_id: @article)
  if @comment.user_id != current_user.id
    flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner of this comment.'
  redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end

# AND

def destroy
  if @comment.destroy
     redirect_to article_path(@article), notice: 'comment deleted successfully'
  else
    redirect_to article_path(@article), alert: 'something went wrong'
  end
end
```

> **Note: Also, I will suggest only show delete option on comment if `comment.user_id == current_user.id`**

Comment: Thanks @Deepak This does seem to have worked.  My comment_auth, also had restrictions on edit and update of the comment, how would I replace that with your method.

And yes, noted about restricting links to destroy to only logged in user.

Comment: Fantastic.  That also works. Thanks. 

So before destroying the comment, am I now finding the associated comment ID and Article ID so we know which comment to destroy?

Comment: yes, so we know whether to let user destroy the comment

Answer (score 0):

adding `@comment = find_comment` to your `comment_auth` method will solve your problem.

```
  def comment_auth
    @comment = find_comment
    if @comment.user_id != current_user.id
      flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner of this comment.'
      redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work... Error message remained the same.